# Let's get the blog going!

Tags: discussion, blog

In the previous episode, we asked:
[Is it worth having a site blog?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/586/is-it-worth-having-a-site-blog) The answer was yes. So let's get going.

What do we need to do? Please read [Rebecca Chernoff's article on Blog Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/):

1. Raise the idea on meta, [check](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/586/is-it-worth-having-a-site-blog).
2. Define the scope. [We have several ideas](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/586/is-it-worth-having-a-site-blog); I propose to start with whatever people are willing to contribute.
3. Recruit contributors. Anyone who's willing to contribute, please raise your hand.
4. Plan a schedule. That's more of a job for the blog coordinator, based on expected contributions. Speaking of which…

I personally nominate [Tony Meyer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/108/tony-meyer) as the overall coordinator for the SFF blog. Everyone else, do you agree, or are there other candidates?

Comment: could you please schedule a short chat event for this for 6th July  21:00?  It doesn't matter if everyone is there or not, but whoever can be around can figure out a plan for starting.  This is in the recommendation chat time (but on the off-week) so hopefully there are people around, and @RebeccaChernoff will try and attend.

Comment: @Tony That's short notice but ok, [status-scheduled](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/science-fiction-fantasy?tab=schedule).

Comment: [Link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/conversation/blog-discussion) to transcript of said chat event.

Comment: See http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/703/how-do-i-contribute-to-the-blog for information about contributing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who's willing to contribute? Please add yourself to this list, and mention what and **how often**.

- [DampeS8N](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/51/dampes8n): I can contribute reviews on occasion, musings on the genre and its tropes, and if it evolves that way, fiction.
- [Keen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1027/keen): episode/season recaps/reviews
- [apoorv020](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/947/apoorv020):Basically interested in fantasy literature, I can do occasional reviews and musings about the same.
- [Gilles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/56/gilles): very occasional book (and perhaps movie) reviews; I'm also willing to be an editor on a regular basis
- [Tony](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/108/tony-meyer): fairly occasional book reviews, organising QotW posts (if we end up having those), editing and overall coordination
- [Pearsonartphoto](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/98/pearsonartphoto): the occasional book review, and perhaps odds and ends statistics about the overall life of the site.
- [Neil Fein](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/33/neilfein): I can contribute book reviews from time to time. (I read fairly slowly, and not all of it SF.)

Comment: @DampeS8N fiction is a fascinating idea.  Perhaps not something to start off with, but definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Tony Meyer: I did a bunch of [Flash Fiction](http://dampes8n.blogspot.com/search/label/Flash%20Fiction) on a blog before. Too much vulgarity to repost, but I'd love to see our blog become a place for authors to get exposure.

Comment: I could do the occasional book review, and perhaps odds and ends statistics about the overall life of the site.

Comment: @DampeS8N @Keen @apoorv020 @Gilles @Pearsonartphoto next time you finish something you're willing to review, please write it up! (see http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/632/lets-get-the-blog-going/646#646 below).

Comment: @DampeS8n found anything worth writing about yet?  If so, please pass it on!  If not, please remember to keep it in mind :)

Comment: @Keen found anything worth writing about yet?  If so, please pass it on!  If not, please remember to keep it in mind :)

Comment: @apoorv020 found anything worth writing about yet?  If so, please pass it on!  If not, please remember to keep it in mind :)

Comment: @NeilFein found anything worth writing about yet?  If so, please pass it on!  If not, please remember to keep it in mind :)

Comment: (Did this "only one @user per comment" restriction exist previously?  It makes comments a crappy way to ping people).

Comment: @Tony - Yeah, this restriction has been around for some time.

Comment: @Tony - Currently reading Charles Stross's *Rule 32*. I'll pass on a review soon, in a week or so.

Comment: @Tony, Giles - I've finished reading the book, can post a review in a few days but I'll need an account to post. I already have a blog account on Bicycles, the blog username is the same as my username here.

Comment: @Gilles can you add neilfein's account (since you have access to his email address) please?  I think the different blogoverflow sites are isolated Wordpress installs, so just using the same username as bicycles should work without any problem.

Comment: @Giles, Tony - Haven't heard anything about this in a long time, so I went ahead and [published a review on my own site](http://magnificentnose.com/2011/09/23/rule-34/). I'd still like to contribute to the blog, though; I'm in the middle China Mieville's *Embassytown* and I'd love to do a review of that when I finish the book.

Comment: @tony - (SE username here) at (gmail) is the username you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I second Tony's nomination.

Comment: Third. And I'm willing to contribute.

Comment: Fourth, and I too am willing to contribute.

Comment: Just take the upvotes (and add 2) as number of members agreeing to the nomination.

Answer (score 5):

Time to start writing!  The site is set up, so we just need to have some content ready and we can kick things off.

- Those that are willing to do reviews, please start keeping this in mind.  Obviously reviews need to wait on consumption of something (book, film, TV) worth reviewing - next time you finish reading/watching something you'd be willing to review, please write one up and let everyone know you've done so.
- Those that are willing to do 'muse' posts, you can start immediately :)  When you've got time, write something up and let everyone know here.
- Please suggest and/or vote for the first [Question of the Full Moon](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/question-of-the-full-moon-1) post.  Pick a question that you'd really like to see more like.

If you'd like to write the content as a draft in the site, email **tony.meyer@gmail.com** (or tweet **tonyandrewmeyer** or get hold of me any other way you'd like) and I'll set up an account for you.  Once everything's all ready to go (e.g. we have a copy of great first posts) we'll start making whatever we have live.

Rebecca suggested that we have a structure for minimal posting (extra posts can be done in addition to this).  For example:

- Shortly after the full moon: a QotFM.
- Fridays: a review.
- Muse Mondays: an opinion/muse post.

(I've randomly picked these days; if anyone cares what they are, please edit this).

Comment: Seems like people could just comment/post here rather than trying to contact you elsewhere...

Comment: That's fine - that's included in "any other way you'd like".  IIUC to set up an account on the site, I need an email address, and not everyone wants to make that public.

Comment: The mods can pull it from their profile, I was not suggesting posting it in public.  Part of why we want a mod as an admin as well. (;

Comment: I'd like to be able to use that blog, so as to fulfill my commitment...

Comment: @Gilles have you been able to make it into the blog site yet?  If so, could you set up Pearsonartphoto's account using the details from his SE account?  If not, then I guess we ask Rebecca to do it.  (And yay for someone getting going!)

Comment: I'd be willing to contribute to the blog, but I would need to know what guidelines to follow. I'm not good with just winging it. I'm a programmer, I need pragmatism and structure ;)

Comment: @OghmaOsiris we don't really have much in the way of guidelines yet :)  What about I ask you (e.g. ping you in chat) if you have anything to contribute after we've got a few things published and we can find some guidelines based on those?