# Question of the Week #1

Tags: discussion, blog

One of the regular posts for the planned [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) is a focus on a question that exemplifies the sort of questions we'd love to see more like.  [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/gaming-questions-of-the-week-1) and [SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1869/top-question-of-the-week-1) do this weekly - we can build up to that, but we probably don't yet have enough really great questions each week to post that frequently.

As a somewhat arbitrary frequency to start with, I've picked the full moon (in NZ, since that's where I am).  So I'll use the highest-voted answer here as of Jul 15 6:40 pm NZDT.  (It's likely that we won't have the blog site up by then, so I'll put the post somewhere everyone can see it until we do).

*UPDATE*: I'll wait three more days and see what happens with this.  I'll think up some sort of reason for choosing that day then ;)

The question doesn't have to be one that has had a lot of views, although that might be a good indicator.  Please post any question that you feel is worthy and explain why. Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  The question doesn't have to be one asked since the last full moon - that's how often we'll feature a question, but it can be any open question.

Standard voting answers, please: one suggestion per answer, and if you like a suggestion then vote it up (if you want to elaborate, add a comment or edit the existing answer).

Comment: The most viewed questions have the [notable badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/47/notable-question). You can [search for high-view questions with a lower threshold](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A1000). 2k users can see the [most viewed questions in the last 30 days](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days). These aren't necessarily what we most want to put forward, just one of the potential criteria.

Comment: Actually, maybe the moon is full at the same time everywhere? Astronomy is not my strong point :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I particularly like this question:

> [Why do we hear Leia's Theme during Kenobi's death?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2810/why-do-we-hear-leias-theme-during-kenobis-death)

I like that it's looking for insight about why a creative decision was made.  A lot of the questions on the site are more in-universe (why or what something happened), and it's nice to see these higher-level questions.

I think the question is quite well written, and certainly provides plenty of detail.  There's only a single answer, but it's an excellent one, so there's not really any need for more.

Comment: Why, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

I admit that I typically only glance over the poetry in any books, and especially the rather long ones in LotR, so I found this question very useful:

> [Lord of the Rings - what is the important background information contained in the poems?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/lord-of-the-rings-what-is-the-important-background-information-contained-in-the)

I think this is a great example of a question because it's something I expect many people would find it useful, and perhaps not otherwise think of asking.  It certainly inspires a truly excellent answer (probably one of my favourite *answers* on the site so far).

Answer (score 2):

My favoritest question on the site is [Is there any artistic representation of Mawhrin-Skel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/is-there-any-artistic-representation-of-mawhrin-skel) Iain M. Banks doesn't write very visual descriptions, and his concepts are odd to us while being perfectly normal parts of their environment. So I was very interested to see how artists have imagined his drones look like, and particularly impressed by [John Rennie](http://www.jonrennie.co.uk/films/79-something-real.html)'s short movie, found by [sebsmith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/833/sebsmith).

However I'm not sure if this is a good question of the full moon, because it's fairly atypical for the site. I'm not so comfortable with it being the first impression of the site. Maybe we can keep it reserve for a summer moon?

Comment: Glad to see that my question was interesting! But do you think we should update the title to remove the name of Mawhrin-Skel and replace it by a more generic mention of culture drones?

Answer (score -1):

I loved seeing the question:

> [What does the blue elevator (?) in this picture refer to?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/what-does-the-blue-elevator-in-this-picture-refer-to)

There's not a lot to the question, really, although there are a couple of nice answers, and the question and answers may have more images than any other on the site!

I think the reason I like this so much is that it reminds me that even something that seems incredibly obvious to me may make no sense to someone else.  I'm sure that all my friends and family, even those with no interest at all in scifi, would recognise the TARDIS, but not everyone has this background (this is maybe particularly true outside of the Commonwealth).

(I'm also reminded of [this chat comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com:80/transcript/message/1050515#1050515)).