# Question of the Week #2

Tags: discussion, blog

**This post is now scheduled to go out in one week's time (September 8th), so please suggest anything great that you've seen before then!**

One of the semi-regular posts for the [blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com) is a focus on a question that exemplifies the sort of questions we'd love to see more like.

The question doesn't have to be one that has had a lot of views, although that might be a good indicator (e.g. [questions that gained the notable badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/47/notable-question), and [via searching](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=views:1000)). Please post any question that you feel is worthy and explain why. Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake. The question doesn't have to be one asked recently - it can be any open question.

The [suggestions from last time](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/question-of-the-week-1) (other than the accepted answer, obviously) can definitely be suggested again.

Standard voting answers, please: one suggestion per answer, and if you like a suggestion then vote it up (if you want to elaborate, add a comment or edit the existing answer).

(I'm using "of the week" in the title here, but that's to catch attention more than anything else. It's not clear whether we have the volume yet to have a featured question every week, so the frequency will likely be lower than that.  Exactly what the frequency will be isn't clear yet :)).

Comment: I think that, for this week, we should stick with the [runner-up from last week](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/645/question-of-the-week-1/652#652) :

http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Directly copied from the previous one).

I admit that I typically only glance over the poetry in any books, and especially the rather long ones in LotR, so I found this question very useful:

> [Lord of the Rings - what is the important background information contained in the poems?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/lord-of-the-rings-what-is-the-important-background-information-contained-in-the)

I think this is a great example of a question because it's something I expect many people would find it useful, and perhaps not otherwise think of asking.  It certainly inspires a truly excellent answer (probably one of my favourite *answers* on the site so far).