# Inappropriate content? Seriously?

Tags: discussion, chat, profanity

With the [profanity discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2384/2565) going on, I [posted an xkcd strip in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/6753918/history) which was even starred! The system decided this was inappropriate and answered:

> your account has been automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content and cannot chat for 29 minutes.

Ignoring for a moment that, from all the webcomics in the net, to my knowledge only xkcd is recognised by the chat system (I just linked to the comic, the system inlined the picture all by itself), does this really make sense at all?

As far as I understand this, it was not flagged by any person, but the system decided on a whim there was something inappropriate and decided to ban me for half an hour. I wouldn't have a problem if it was somebody who found this offensive but the system censoring the chat?

What do you think about this?

Comment: What was the XKCD link? (you can safely post in comments, it won't auto-expand)

Comment: @DVK: xkcd.com/75

Comment: For the record, I don't see how that flag should have been considered valid.

Comment: @Gilles: So noted :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no automatic flagging in chat, the automatic part of that message just refers to the suspension part.

Either at least 6 regular users with 10k+ chat reputation or one moderator validated a flag on this message. These flags are shown to all active 10k+ users and mods on the whole of chat.SE.

Comment: I already wondered if somebody really bothered to implement some text-recognition or alike for flagging.