# How much vulgarity is too much?

Tags: discussion, profanity

I've been on this site for 11 months now and have deducted that vulgar language has been generally looked down upon here. But there have been instances where I have come across people(not naming them) using words like :

> Shit, bullshit and more.

So I ask - Till what extent is abusive language tolerated here?  Now don't get me wrong I certainly don't mean racially abusive language but is the usage of words like -

> Fuck

OK??

Comment: Related: [Is profanity in direct quotes from source material permitted?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2384/7957)

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, coarse language should not be used gratuitously. Sometimes it can't be avoided, because of the existence of such unfortunate titles as "The Big Space Fuck" by one of our more overrated writers.

Comment: Additionally, it sometimes comes up that one needs to actually use the word to indicate the word, as per answers to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271227/cranks-effing-turners